# How to show erros occuring during installation of prerequesites

Tags: installation, wix, bundle

Using Wix 3.10

When installing .NET 4.6 on Windows 8.0, the Microsoft package returns an error since the computer is missing anothger kb by microsoft. That's ok so far, but I want to show this message from the NET-installer in my custom wpf-UI, but I didn't figured out what event will trigger.

In my viewmodel I have the current instance of the BootstrapperApplication and my first approach will not log anything:

```
 internal MainViewModel(BootstrapperApplication model, Action<LogLevel, string> onLoggerAction, (....))
{
  this.Model = model;
  this.Model.DetectPackageComplete += this.DetectPackageComplete;
  this.Model.DetectRelatedBundle += new EventHandler<DetectRelatedBundleEventArgs>(this.Model_DetectRelatedBundle);
  this.Model.DetectPriorBundle += new EventHandler<DetectPriorBundleEventArgs>(this.Model_DetectPriorBundle);
  this.Model.DetectRelatedMsiPackage += new EventHandler<DetectRelatedMsiPackageEventArgs>(this.Model_DetectRelatedMsiPackage);
  this.Model.DetectTargetMsiPackage += new EventHandler<DetectTargetMsiPackageEventArgs>(this.Model_DetectTargetMsiPackage);
  this.Model.Error += this.SetupError;
  [...]
}

public void SetupError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
{
   this.onLoggerAction(LogLevel.Standard, string.Format("Error occured. Message: {0}", args.ErrorMessage));
   this.onLoggerAction(LogLevel.Standard, string.Format("Error occured. ErrorCode: {0}", args.ErrorCode));
   this.onLoggerAction(LogLevel.Standard, string.Format("Error occured. Type: {0}", args.ErrorType));
   this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.ShowErrorView(args)));
}
```

The log file shows the error:

```
[07D0:06D4][2016-05-09T09:16:36]i301: Applying execute package: Netfx4FullInternal, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3049A85843EAF65E89E2336D5FE6E85E416797BE\NDP46-KB3045557-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\3049A85843EAF65E89E2336D5FE6E85E416797BE\NDP46-KB3045557-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" /passive /norestart'
[07D0:06D4][2016-05-09T09:18:11]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Process returned error: 0x13ec
[07D0:06D4][2016-05-09T09:18:11]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0928:09AC][2016-05-09T09:18:11]e000: Error 0x800713ec: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package
```

But how can I handle this error?

Comment: It works now. Ich had a stupid mistake referecing my ba.dll in the bundle.wxs. I get the (cryptic) return codes, but not the ErrorMessage in the ExecutePackageCompleted-event. But for now I can inform the user that there went something wrong, but getting the real ErrorMessage from the underlaying installer would be nice

Answer (score 0):

You already have the "/norestart" and "/passive" arguments in use, try using the "/log C:\pathtolog\yourlog.log" aswell so you can see what goes wrong.

Before shipping your installer you should have fixed all the errors, not display them all.

Imagine installing something and thousands of errors show up....

Comment: The .Net framework logs in the %temp%-folder per defailt, so I am able ti get the real error, but not in my setup ui. Here the problem is not easy to solve. On a new windows 8.1 installation the .Net 4.6 installer doesn't work unless another kb by Microsoft is installed, and even this kb had another kb it was depending from. So these things my setup can't handle for all configurations outside without getting huge.